# Token Expiry in Schema Model Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When a user logs in my app, a token is generated and saved in a mongoDB collection. This token is supposed to be valid for 100 hours and then expire, so that the user has to generate a new one. This is my schema code :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const tokenSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "user",
  },
  token: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    expires: 360000,// this is the expiry time in seconds
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("token", tokenSchema);
```

But this doesn't seem to work and my tokens are deleted unexpectedly from the mongo collection. Am I doing something wrong?

This is when the token is created at login :

```
 const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        email: loadedUser.email,
        userId: loadedUser._id.toString()
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      { expiresIn: '1000h' }
    );
    const newToken = new Token({
      "userId": user._id,
      "token" : token
      
  });
    await newToken.save();
```

Comment: You can use jwt with exp.